# Caching an intermediate dataframe when there is only one action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

In Spark, let's say that I have a dataframe that undergoes some 100 transformations and then there is a single action applied. Will caching an intermediate dataframe help under any circumstances? I can see that caching will help when there is more than one action applied on a dataframe but how about a single action?

To clarify:
I have a dataframe A using which I obtain 2 different dataframes B and C. Then I do a union of B and C to form D on which I apply an action. Imagine this happening in a very complicated scenario with lots of branches. Will caching A speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching a DataFrame has no benefit on the first time it needs to be evaluated (in fact it actually has a performance cost and obviously increases memory use).  It's only on reuse that caching helps.

If you split A into B and C, then use both B and C, you've just used A twice, so caching it will help.

Number of Actions is not an important measure, what matters is the execution path.